# Securing pages with flask user login/authentication

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I've done a lot of development with flask but haven't delved into securing web applications with a user authentication. For the sake of this example lets
assume I have the basic set up

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

# Can't be accessed if not logged in
@app.route('/secure')
def secure():
    # pseudo code
    if user != authenticated:
        return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render_template('secure.html')

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')

# Called from the login page form
@app.route('/authenticate')
def authenticate():
    # do some code to authenticate, pseudo
    if username in DB and password == password-hash:
        user = authenticated
        return redirect('/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I'm able to use mongodb and add/remove/query data. My issue is I don't know how to tie the two together. A user creates an account, the data is added to the DB, a user logs in, the input it queried against the DB, if it matches they can access the site.

The problem I get to is how do I let my Flask application know that after the user has provided correct credentials to remember/know who they are and allow them to access restricted pages. I guess how do I track the authentication status up until they logout.

note: would like to know the most secure method of multi-user authentication in Flask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need an API that handles http methods.  Flask-restful and Flask-httpauth you could write code that looks like this:

```
@marshal_with(piece_fields)
    @auth.login_required
    def post(self):
        args = self.reqparse.parse_args()
        piece = models.Piece.create(**args)
        return piece, 201,
        {'Location': url_for('resources.pieces.Piece', id=Piece.id)}
```

Where @auth.login_required is basic or token http authentication (defined in a separate file called auth.py) that wraps around your http methods.  They would require http requests to be sent with username and password or token.  Hope this helps!

Comment: What about something like flask session? I've done a tutorial with that, is that no good for multiple users?